# Configuring TEXINPUTS from AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex, texinputs

I'm working on a collaborative (version controlled) LaTeX project.  We have a bunch of custom `.sty` files in a subdirectory of our project named `tex`.  We set `TEXINPUTS=".:tex:"` in the project `Makefile` so that we can use `\usepackage{foo}` instead of `\usepackage{tex/foo}`.  This avoids annoying LaTeX warnings and avoids the need to modify those `.sty` files that `\input` or `\RequirePackage` another file in the same `tex` directory.  All of this works well.

What *doesn't* work well is AUCTeX.  We add the following to the bottom of each of our LaTeX sources:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../relative/path/to/main.tex"
%%% End:
```

Unfortunately, hitting `C-c C-c LaTeX` results in an error because `TEXINPUTS` isn't set properly.

Here are my questions:

- Is there a TeX macro that allows us to change the TeX input search path from within the document itself?
- Is there a non-risky file local variable we can use to tell AUCTeX to set `TEXINPUTS` when it runs LaTeX?
- Is there an alternative approach we can take?  I don't want each user to have to modify his/her environment before starting emacs.

Comment: Have you tried setting `TEXINPUTS` from a shell (`export TEXINPUTS=.:tex:${TEXINPUTS}` in `bash` syntax) and invoking AUCTeX from there?

Comment: @Daniel:  Yes, and that works, but I don't want each user to have to modify his/her environment before starting emacs.

Answer (score 6):

```
%%% Local Variables:
...
%%% eval: (setenv "TEXINPUTS" "--place your setting here---")
...
```

Look in to this thread for some more information
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2005-05/msg00097.html

Comment: I'm looking for a safe file local variable I can set -- adding `eval: (setenv "TEXINPUTS" ...)` results in a warning when the file is visited.